# Populate a field in form alter with user name and one with user ID

Tags: 8, forms

can someone tell me why this works

```
function justatest_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  global $user;
  if ( $form_id == 'node_test_form'){
    $form['field_owner']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'test';
  }
  return $form;
}
```

but this doesn't

```
function justatest_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

      global $user;
      if ( $form_id == 'node_test_form'){
        $form['field_owner']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $user->uid;
      }
      return $form;
    }
```

I'd also like to know how I get the current users name too, if someone can assist with that it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please consider adding and accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The D8 `uid` property reference isn't something that can be cast into a string as you could in D7.

In D7, user objects use a generic PHP object class (`stdClass`) with a `uid` property containing a string. In D8, user objects use a `Drupal\user\Entity\User` class. This class does't have a *direct* `uid` string property.

In D8 the `uid` property [magically retrieves](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3A__get/8.2.x) the User entity [field property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemList.php/class/FieldItemList/8.2.x) instead of a simple uid string.

As such, there are other new methods/properties (as you've mentioned) to retrieve the underlying uid value.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
// Load the current user. 
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id()); 

// retrieve field data from that user 
$name = $user->get('name')->value; 
$uid= $user->get('uid')->value;
```

Then you can just use

```
$form['field_owner']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $uid;
```

or

```
$form['field_owner']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $name;
```

Thanks for looking, if there is a better way then please let me know

Gibbo